# Adding data to Chart.js line graph from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I use the code below to display data stored in dataGraph, measureAttr stores the attributes. How can I add the data in a loop for different array sizes?

```
currentChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'],
                datasets: [{
                    data: dataGraph[0],
                    label: measureAttr[0],
                    backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
                    fill: false
                }, {
                    data: dataGraph[1],
                    label: measureAttr[1],
                    backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
                    fill: false
                }, {
                    data: dataGraph[2],
                    label: measureAttr[2],
                    backgroundColor: "#3cba9f",
                    fill: false
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                }
            }
```

I already tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
   for (i = 0; i < measureAttr.length; i++) {
        currentChart.data.datasets.label.push(measureAttr[i]);
        currentChart.data.datasets.data.push(dataGraph[i]);
        currentChart.update();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out myself, this worked:

```
for (i = 0; i < measureAttr.length; i++) {
        const newDataSet = {
            label: measureAttr[i],
            data: dataGraph[i],
            backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
            fill: false
    }
    currentChart.data.datasets.push(newDataSet);
}

currentChart.update();
```